# Transfer control of terminal process to a different emulator

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, session

How can I transfer running terminal session between PCs on-the-fly? I mean - I'd like to be able to transfer for example SSH session with running application to another PC lets say laptop, without shell interruption. Or move SSH session from laptop to host physical machine so I'd be able to turn off laptop and continue directly on host machine and vice versa. Is it possible?

I'm interested especially in SSH to SSH migration, but it would be nice if local terminal to SSH transfer would be possible as well.

Comment: Is using `screen` not an option? Please also have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12101/pass-my-credentials-from-a-ssh-session-to-another-ssh-session